# Unable to find a specification for `FlutterMacOS` depended upon by `shared_preferences_foundation`

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I dont really understand why this error shown to me. Can anyone help with this?

Regardless of shared_preferences version it always installs shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1)

after i hit pod install this error was shown to me

Answer (score 1):

You maybe use a private pod source in your podfile

add this source in your podfile, pod install again

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have any idea why this is needed ?

Answer (score 0):

I had changed code below than it work, but I don't know why in ios platform declare using osx?

`example/ios/.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/ios/shared_preferences_foundation.podspec`

comment this line:   # s.osx.dependency 'FlutterMacOS'